# commands in bash script doesn't work properly

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I have this script :

```
#!/bin/bash
./process-list $1 
det=$?
echo $det
if [ $det -eq 1 ]
then
   echo "!!!"
   ssh -n -f 192.0.2.1 "/usr/local/bin/sshfs -r 192.0.2.2:/home/sth/rootcheck_redhat /home/ossl7/r"
   rk=$(ssh -n -f 192.0.2.1 'cd /home/s/r/rootcheck-2.4; ./ossec-rootcheck >&2; echo $?' 2>res)
if [ $rk -eq 0 ]
then
   echo "not!" 
fi
fi
exit;
```

I `ssh` to system `192.0.2.1` and run `sshfs` command on it. actualy I want to mount a directory of system `192.0.2.2` on system `192.0.2.1` and then run a program (which is located in that directory) on system `192.0.2.1`. all these `ssh` and `sshfs` commands work properly. when I run them manually and output of program `ossec-rootcheck` is written to file `res` ,but when I run this script, mount is done but no output is written to file `res`. I guess program `ossec-rootcheck` is runned but I don't know why the output isn't written!
this script used to work properly before I don't know what happend suddenly!

Comment: Could it be that there is no writing permission any more on that mounted volume? Check by doing the steps manually, so in an interactive session instead of that script.

Comment: Is 192.*.*.1 a placeholder because you don't want to reveal the precise address to us, or is that the big glaring error in your script right there?

Comment: @arkascha:I mentioned that I runned the commands interactively(manually means without script) and they work properly!

Comment: @tripleee:yes its the ip address and I dont want to reveal the precise address

Comment: You executed the steps manually using the same user account?

Comment: @arkascha: yes I executed each command on the related system and with the same account that I run the script for them too.

Comment: There must be some difference. If everything were the same in manual and script based execution then the same thing would happen. Maybe a race condition, since typically scripts run faster than manually typed commands?

Comment: If that's a correct diagnosis, adding a `sleep 5` after the `sshfs` command might help.

Comment: @arkascha: I just copy and paste that commands from script and they executed totally ok!!!! I really dont know why the script doesn't work

Comment: @tripleee: I did it. no use!

Comment: I've edited the question to use addresses from the block of IP space reserved for examples; see http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5737 for details.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the program, the remote machine has stdin>stderr, but how do you get that to the local machine where ssh is being evaluated?

The end ' means on the rk= line, the 2>res happens locally. (and there is no error from ssh, the remote error, if any, is lost when ssh successfully completes.) You could try `>res` it will get whatever ssh prints out, unfortunately including non-errors.

Comment: :you mean some overwriting is happening?I dont think so because I changed that line and I trie `ssh -n -f 192.*.*.1 'cd /home/s/r/rootcheck-2.4; ./ossec-rootcheck >&2; echo $2'` but still nothing happens!